# Can I use two different Apple ID to apply different Developer ID for one app?

Tags: macos, certificate

I applied a developer ID for my app,but it failed to be signed.I tried to apply a new ID(another apple id,same reason),but  Apple rejected it.How can I succeed to get a developer ID?

Comment: Are you signing it with your "Distribution" certificate? In order for the application to be distributed it needs to be signed with "Distribution Certificate" which is created in the Apple Developer Portal. You will also need to create an app id and assign it to said certificate. You will need to make sure you Certificates have been loaded you can do this by going into Xcode > Preference> Your Apple ID > View Details Bottom Right> and Then Download All

Comment: The Developer ID is used for kext signing

Answer (score 0):

You need to join Apple program to sign your developer ID.[This may help you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html).

I would have commented it but dont have enough reputaion.

Comment: I've connected the Apple Support.